# Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘mapview’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, macos

Trying to install "mapview" R package on macos 10.14.6, but got multiple errors.

```py
> install.packages("mapview", dependencies = T)
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘leafem’, ‘sf’, ‘lwgeom’, ‘stars’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/leafem_0.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2844830 bytes (2.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.7 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/sf_0.8-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 8607770 bytes (8.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 8.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lwgeom_0.1-7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 439906 bytes (429 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 429 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/stars_0.3-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 8818766 bytes (8.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 8.4 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/mapview_2.7.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2029313 bytes (1.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.9 MB

* installing *source* package ‘sf’ ...
** package ‘sf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
configure: CC: clang
configure: CXX: clang++ -std=gnu++11
checking for gdal-config... /usr/local/bin/gdal-config
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 2.4.2
checking GDAL version >= 2.0.1... yes
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... clang -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking gdal.h usability... yes
checking gdal.h presence... yes
checking for gdal.h... yes
checking GDAL: linking with --libs only... yes
checking GDAL: /usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/share/gdal/pcs.csv readable... yes
checking GDAL: checking whether PROJ is available for linking:... yes
checking GDAL: checking whether PROJ is available fur running:... yes
configure: pkg-config proj exists, will use it
configure: using proj.h.
configure: PROJ: 6.2.0
checking PROJ: checking whether PROJ and sqlite3 are available for linking:... yes
checking for geos-config... /usr/local/bin/geos-config
checking geos-config usability... yes
configure: GEOS: 3.7.2
checking GEOS version >= 3.4.0... yes
checking geos_c.h usability... yes
checking geos_c.h presence... yes
checking for geos_c.h... yes
checking geos: linking with -L/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/lib -lgeos_c... yes
configure: Package CPP flags:  -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include
configure: Package LIBS: -L/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/lib -lproj   -L/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/lib -lgdal -L/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/lib -lgeos_c
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c bbox.cpp -o bbox.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c gdal.cpp -o gdal.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c gdal_geom.cpp -o gdal_geom.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c gdal_read.cpp -o gdal_read.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c gdal_utils.cpp -o gdal_utils.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c gdal_write.cpp -o gdal_write.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c geos.cpp -o geos.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c hex.cpp -o hex.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c ops.cpp -o ops.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c polygonize.cpp -o polygonize.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c proj.cpp -o proj.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c proj_info.cpp -o proj_info.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c raster2sf.cpp -o raster2sf.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c sfg.cpp -o sfg.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c signed_area.cpp -o signed_area.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c stars.cpp -o stars.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c wkb.cpp -o wkb.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o sf.so RcppExports.o bbox.o gdal.o gdal_geom.o gdal_read.o gdal_utils.o gdal_write.o geos.o hex.o ops.o polygonize.o proj.o proj_info.o raster2sf.o sfg.o signed_area.o stars.o wkb.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/proj/6.2.0/lib -lproj -L/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_2/lib -lgdal -L/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.2/lib -lgeos_c -L/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1_1/lib/R/lib -lR -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/00LOCK-sf/00new/sf/libs
** R
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/KernSmooth/libs/KernSmooth.so':
  dlopen(/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/KernSmooth/libs/KernSmooth.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/KernSmooth/libs/KernSmooth.so
  Reason: image not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... asNamespace -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/sf’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘sf’ is not available for package ‘leafem’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/leafem’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘leafem’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘sf’ is not available for package ‘lwgeom’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/lwgeom’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lwgeom’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘sf’ is not available for package ‘stars’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/stars’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stars’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘leafem’, ‘sf’ are not available for package ‘mapview’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/mapview’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mapview’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/wf/dwptnn_s5_q3c22cdw_ymr4h0000gn/T/RtmpXmC4xO/downloaded_packages’
```

How can I properly install this package?

install.packages("mapview", dependencies = T)
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘leafem’, ‘sf’, ‘lwgeom’, ‘stars’

Comment: Try first install prerequisite packages manually .